# Excel VB subscript out of range repairing macro

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the declaration of navrec

```
Public navrec(1 To 100000, 100) As Variant


navrec(r,c) = Cells(r,c)
```

I encounter a subscript out of range error on the above for loop line within the below procedure

I am attempting to repair this macro with limited working knowledge of VB-Excel. I am assuming the preceding for loop ranges' `navreclr` & `navreclc` are referencing too large of a data area?

```
Sub import_navr()

EntityList = mywkb.Sheets("Source Files").Range("nrlist")
navreclr = 0
days = 0

fname = navrecloc

If Dir(fname) = "" Then
MsgBox ("Please save current PVAL. Macro will end")
End
End If

Workbooks.Open fname, ReadOnly:=True
Set tempbk = ActiveWorkbook

navreclr = Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
navreclc = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

 For r = 1 To navreclr
    For c = 1 To navreclc
            navrec(r, c) = Cells(r, c)
    Next c
 Next r

For c = 1 To navreclc
    If navrec(1, c) = "ENTITY_ID" Then einr = c
    If navrec(1, c) = "SHARE_CLASS" Then scnr = c
    If navrec(1, c) = "LEDGER_ITEMS" Then linr = c
    If navrec(1, c) = "BALANCE_CHANGE" Then bcnr = c
Next c


Set ofs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
mywkb.Sheets("Source Files").Range("nrlist").Cells(1, 2) = ofs.GetFile(fname).Datelastmodified

tempbk.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your array, `navrec`, is not the correct size to hold all of the cells. You can fix this by adding the following code directly above your loop (I've included the loop below):

```
ReDim navrec(navreclr, navreclc) As Variant

For r = 1 To navreclr
    For c = 1 To navreclc
        navrec(r, c) = Cells(r, c)
    Next c
Next r
```

When you are determining the dimensions of your array dynamically, as in this example, it is generally best to declare the array dynamically as well, and not use a constant size. Try not to overutilize memory unless there is a good reason to do so.

You will also need to declare the variable dimensionless in the global module, or you will get an error stating "Array already dimensioned."

Replace:

```
Public navrec(1 To 100000, 100) As Variant
```

with

```
Public navrec() As Variant
```

to eliminate this error.

Comment: This procedure is one of many. The original declaration for navrec is `Public navrec(1 To 100000, 100) As Variant` I added your adjustments and the code says the variable has already been dimensioned. I am unsure as to whether I should edit the public declaration which appears to be a global variable.

Comment: Check the update to my post. Declare `navrec` dimensionless and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up the value of a rectangular array directly in one operation:

```
Set tempbk = Workbooks.Open(fname, ReadOnly:=True)

With tempbk.Sheets(1)
    'get row/col counts
    navreclr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    navreclc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'assign range value to array
    nacrec = .cells(1).Resize(navreclr, navreclc).Value

End With
```